# Cannot create MVC project in VS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, asp.net-mvc-2

After installing the official VisualStudio 2010 (had installed and uninstalled RC before) I cannot create MVC projects.
When I try to create a new "MvcWebApplicationProjectTemplate.cs" project, I got the following error message:

[alt text http://img202.imageshack.us/img202/8506/mvcerror.jpg](http://img202.imageshack.us/img202/8506/mvcerror.jpg)

Reinstalling MVC 2.0 didn't helped :(

Comment: Before you installed VS2010, did you uninstall MVC in addition to VS2010? The proper steps were to uninstall MVC first and then VS2010 second (not sure if this was documented anywhere but is what we determined with some internal tests).

Comment: ok, uninstalling VS and MVC. Then install VS2010 first, then MVC?

Comment: the release of VS2010 comes with MVC, so you should not have to install separately once you've uninstalled VS2010 RC and the separate MVC

Comment: The steps we determined were needed when you're in a state with VS2010 RC and MVC2 (RC or RTM) were: 1) Uninstall MVC 2) Uninstall VS RC 3) Install VS2010 RTM (this includes MVC 2 RTM). But it seemed important to uninstall MVC BEFORE you uninstalled VS. There were cases where it wasn't necessary but there were cases where it was necessary. We just determined that this order ALWAYS worked. The problem, I think, was when MVC RC bits remained and you installed VS2010 RTM on top of those bits (which I suspect may be your case).

Comment: hmm, stared uninstalling VS2010 RTM first... will uninstall all VS bits and MVC, and we will see.
I think previously I have uninstalled VS2010 RC first, then MVC 2

Comment: WAG:  What version of the framework are you targeting?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, had to uninstall VS2010, all MVC bits, then reinstalled VS2010 and it works!

And the mvc template now is named 'ASP.NET MVC 2 Web Application' instead of 'MvcWebApplicationProjectTemplate'